# IOError: No such file or directory:

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

```
 # pick up the file which needs to be processed
    current_file = file_names[0]
    print "Processing current file: " + current_file

    key = bucket.get_key(current_file)
    print "Processing key: " + str(key)
    key.get_contents_to_filename(working_dir + "test_stats_temp.dat")
    print "Current directory: ",outputdir
    print "File to process:",current_file
```

Processing test output for: ds=2013-08-27

Processing current file: output/test_count_day/ds=2013-08-27/task_201308270934_0003_r_000000

Processing key: Key: hadoop.test.com,output/test_count_day/ds=2013-08-27/task_201308270934_0003_r_000000

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "queue_consumer.py", line 493, in <module>
        test_process.load_test_cnv_stats_daily(datestring,working_dir,mysqlconn,s3_conn,test_output_bucket,test_output)
      File "/home/sbr/aaa/test_process.py", line 46, in load_test_cnv_stats_daily
        key.get_contents_to_filename(working_dir + "test_stats_temp.dat")
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/key.py", line 1275, in get_contents_to_filename
        fp = open(filename, 'wb')
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sbr/aaa/test_stats_temp.dat'
```

I got this error, when I fetched data to DB from S3 output. I'm confused here. How to handle this issue?

Comment: Does your `working_dir` exist?

Comment: @datasage - you could turn your comment into an answer, even if it's a quick fix. Provides better visibility in case anyone faces this in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/sbr/aaa/test_stats_temp.dat'`

Indicates that the path set with `working_dir` does not exist. Creating the directory will fix it.

Comment: @brisk did it?  Because I'm getting a similar issue and this solution doesn't work for me